# Bootstrap Input width changes when validation classes applied

Tags: validation, input, bootstrap-4, width

I have created a search form with **form-inline** class. When I add **is-invalid** or **is-valid** classes to input, input width changed. How to fix width of input control.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mt-2">
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">
    <!-- Other tags... -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
      <form class="form-inline float-sm-right">
        <select class="form-control mr-1">
        <option>First Name</option>
        <option>Last Name</option>
        <option>Phone</option>
        <option>Email</option>
        </select>
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-1" type="text">
        <button class="btn btn-dark my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">
        Search
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see a demo on [this link](https://www.codeply.com/p/WP50GNC16w)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry, in this case, the text in the field will not be displayed correctly. You must correct fields without the is-invalid and is-valid classes

```css
.form-inline input:not(.is-invalid),
.form-inline input:not(.is-valid) {
    padding-right: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem);
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize this. I try with long text text was not display correctly. After change css to last one text is displayed well.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.was-validated .form-control:invalid, .form-control.is-invalid,
.was-validated .form-control:valid, .form-control.is-valid {
        padding-right: 0.75rem;
}
```